# How are asp.net thread pool managed priority wise?

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading, asynchronous, iis-7

We have a computation intensive web application that serves only a few dozen user at any given time at  most. However, we have encountered situations where some task performed by just one user can prevent the entire site from processing any other request.

I read that the thread pool has by default up to 128 threads.  How can a single thread deprive the remaining threads from cpu time?  How does that work? Is this the operating system juging that data access as an example requires higher priority since TCP connection should be kept reliable to sql server in case a large dataset is beeing fethched or saved?

Can someone with a deeper insight with how things actually work enlighten me on this?

How about multi core CPU? We have 8 cpu cores on the server. will they participate in the processing or do we have to increase the number of process/actively engage into parallel processing to take advantage of the multi-core environnment?

Comment: Not enough information. Normally a single thread can't tie up the CPU like that. Something else (a shared resource) must be in play.

Comment: This sounds like a really good hint. I have some lookup tables for dictionaries and vocabularies that are cached. These are extensively used and i have decided to cache them following best practices recommandation. Could that be it?